# SQL Query Left Outer Join with specific record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query like this

```
SELECT P9_IR259_FI, FX_IR259_SYS_PROD_TYP, FX_IR259_SLS_POS, FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL, PX_IR259_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_NAME, SUPERNAME, SUPERCDE, SUPERPOS 
FROM IR259 K 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT FX_IR259_NAME AS SUPERNAME ,FX_IR259_SLS_POS AS SUPERPOS, PX_IR259_OFC_CDE AS SUPERCDE 
         FROM IR259 M 
         WHERE P9_IR259_FI = 75214 AND FX_IR259_SLS_POS = 2 AND FX_IR259_NAME LIKE 'ME%'
         ) ON K.FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE = SUPERCDE 
 WHERE 
    FX_IR259_SLS_POS = '1' 
    AND FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL = 'BRO' 
    AND F9_IR259_CRE_TMS > 00000000000000000 
ORDER BY FX_IR259_SLS_POS, FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL
```

but result seems not correct means, i want to show SUPERNAME like 'ME%' only

[image]

the result show the SUPERNAME with like 'ME%' but other records have show too.

Thanks for Advice

Comment: Please format the query in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another filter to the where clause.

```
WHERE 
    FX_IR259_SLS_POS = '1' 
    AND FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL = 'BRO' 
    AND F9_IR259_CRE_TMS > 00000000000000000 
    AND SUPERNAME LIKE 'ME%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add another condition in the where clause

```
SELECT P9_IR259_FI, FX_IR259_SYS_PROD_TYP, FX_IR259_SLS_POS, FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL, PX_IR259_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_NAME, SUPERNAME, SUPERCDE, SUPERPOS 
FROM IR259 K 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT FX_IR259_NAME AS SUPERNAME ,FX_IR259_SLS_POS AS SUPERPOS, PX_IR259_OFC_CDE AS SUPERCDE 
          FROM IR259 M 
         WHERE P9_IR259_FI = 75214 AND FX_IR259_SLS_POS = 2 AND FX_IR259_NAME LIKE 'ME%'
         ) ON K.FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE = SUPERCDE 
 WHERE 
    FX_IR259_SLS_POS = '1' 
    AND FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL = 'BRO' 
    AND F9_IR259_CRE_TMS > 00000000000000000 
    AND SUPERNAME LIKE 'ME%'
ORDER BY FX_IR259_SLS_POS, FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P9_IR259_FI, FX_IR259_SYS_PROD_TYP, FX_IR259_SLS_POS, FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL, PX_IR259_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_NAME, SUPERNAME, SUPERCDE, SUPERPOS 
FROM 
(select * from IR259 where SUPERNAME like 'ME%') K 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT FX_IR259_NAME AS SUPERNAME ,FX_IR259_SLS_POS AS SUPERPOS, PX_IR259_OFC_CDE AS SUPERCDE 
         FROM IR259 M 
         WHERE P9_IR259_FI = 75214 AND FX_IR259_SLS_POS = 2 AND FX_IR259_NAME LIKE 'ME%'
         ) ON K.FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE = SUPERCDE 
 WHERE 
    FX_IR259_SLS_POS = '1' 
    AND FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL = 'BRO' 
    AND F9_IR259_CRE_TMS > 00000000000000000 
ORDER BY FX_IR259_SLS_POS, FX_IR259_SPR_OFC_CDE, FX_IR259_SLS_CHNL
```